# Converting from old VB to .NET C# and what does 0xe10L means?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, vb6-migration, vb.net-to-c#

I am converting from old VB to .NET C# and I get the following in C# code. What does the following lines mean? I know it has to do with date and time difference but I can't make out the exact comparison. Please help me.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

int num = (int)((0xe10L - DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Client.last_use_date, now, FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday, FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1)) + 30L);
```

what does `0xe10L` means and what is it being compared to? how about `30L`?

```
if (DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, current.last_use_date, now, FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday, FirstWeekOfYear.Jan1) >= 0x3dL)
```

what does `0x3dL` means?

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts:

- 0x3D is the hex value of the integer (in this case decimal 61)
- "L" means long (i.e., 64 bits, not 32).

The reason for the explicit long is because DateDiff returns a long.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Should have thought of this! I am impressed on how fast I got these answers.

Comment: If one of these is the "answer" you should mark it as the answer - people will be more inclined to help answer questions when you select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's the hex representation for the decimal value, such as 3600.  (0x => hex E10 = 3600) which is the number of seconds in an hour.

0x3D is saying 61, so the second equation is checking for > 1 hour (> 61 mins).